# Angular <mat-select> shows an error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, data-binding, angular-material

In the template, I'm using mat-select but in console, there is showing the below problem.
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined"

I didn't use any pipe here but why it arises? If I comment out that(mat-select) portion the error doesn't come up. What will be the solution?

```
            // component.html file

            <div class="grid-dropdown">
            <mat-label>Choose Organization</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOrgId" placeholder="Select Org" name="batch" (selectionChange)="orgChange(selectedOrgId)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of loadedOrganization" [value]="option.org_id">{{ option.org_name }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
           </div>

          // component.ts file
          
           orgChange(e: any) {
              console.log('selection works=>', e);
           }
```

If I select any option, orgChange() method will be triggered and the respective method should call in ts file. But that's not gonna happen. I think the above error may cause this problem.

Comment: Did you have any Class/Interface with the property named `pipe` within it? If yes, are you trying to set any value to this property on your method `orgChange`? Please describe all your code parts that are associated with this HTML snippet (components, classes, services and interfaces).

Comment: It's just a component class. And this orgChange() method declared after ngOnit() method.